# Is there a "map" function in php?

Tags: php, dictionary, range

I am trying to find a php equivalent of processing's "map" function so I can re-map a number from one range to another. Does anything exist? Is it called something different?

http://processing.org/reference/map_.html

For example to map a value from 0-100 to 0-9.

```
map(75, 0, 100, 0, 9);
```

Comment: I just want to point out how easy this function would be to write yourself. If it turns out this is not built in to PHP I'll do it for you (if somebody else doesn't do it first)

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to `0+((75*(9-0))/(100-0))`?

Comment: Yes, its no problem to write myself I was just curious if a native function was available, I have always heard that native functions will always be faster than a custom written function (when basic algorithms are concerned).

Comment: You shouldn't worry about that kind of micro optimization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no native function for doing this, but it's easy to create:

```
function map($value, $low1, $high1, $low2, $high2) {
    return ($value / ($high1 - $low1)) * ($high2 - $low2) + $low2;
}
```

This is untested, but you should hopefully get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for answering my main question (if a native function exists) and also provided an example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this great function!

I would personally improve a bit this function by adding simple error checking, to avoid dividing by 0, which would make PHP have a fatal error.

```
function map($value, $low1, $high1, $low2, $high2) {
    if ($low1 == $high1)
         return $low1;

    return ($value / ($high1 - $low1)) * ($high2 - $low2) + $low2;
}
```